# Why are images not displaying when using the ajaxtoolkit:slideshowextender?

Tags: c#, asp.net, slideshow, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm trying to implement an 'ajaxToolkit:SlideShowExtender' attribute based on the demo code available online, also tried the code from GitHub as posted in one of the answers below.

Things I tried:

- I looked in the Web.config file of my site to make sure the 'control' for 'ajaxToolkit' was there and it is.
- I've installed 'AJAX Control Toolkit V18.1' through the NuGet manager so I believe the dll is correctly installed.
- I checked the image path, which is OK.
- There may be something missing or wrong with the ScriptManager, which is configured on my 'Site.master' page and I can't add it to the aspx page as it can only contain one ScriptManager.
- I am also unable to add the tag 'ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager' as it is not recognized. It says it's not a known element.
- I also tried moving the GetSlides() method to the Site.master.cs file, but no luck.
- I cleared my browser data (history, download, cookies, cached images and files)

From my *Test.aspx* file:

```
<%@ Page Title="Test" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit"%>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">

    <table style="align-content:center; width:500px; height:250px;">
        <tr style="align-content:center;">
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="#000000" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="align-content:center;">
            <td>
                <asp:Image runat="server" ID="Image1" Height="250" Width="400" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="text-align:center;">
            <td>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgBtnPrevious" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Buttons/back.png"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="BtnPlayStop" runat="server" BackColor="Black" ForeColor="White"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgBtnNext" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Buttons/forward.png"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <ajaxToolkit:SlideShowExtender ID="SlideShowExtender1" runat="server" 
        AutoPlay="true" ImageTitleLabelID="Label1" PlayInterval="2000" Loop="true" PlayButtonID="BtnPlayStop"
        PlayButtonText="Play" StopButtonText="Stop" PreviousButtonID="ImgBtnPrevious" NextButtonID="ImgBtnNext"
        SlideShowAnimationType="SlideRight" TargetControlID="Image1" SlideShowServiceMethod="GetSlides" />

</asp:Content>
```

(My image buttons are showing up OK)

My code behind (*Test.aspx.cs* file):

As you can see, I tried three different ways of displaying the images.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using AjaxControlToolkit;
using System.IO;

public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
    public AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] GetSlides()
    {
        /*
        List<Slide> slides = new List<Slide>();
        string myimgdir = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images/Test/");

        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(myimgdir);
        var myslides = from displayimg in dir.GetFiles()
                       select new Slide
                       {
                           Name = displayimg.Name,
                           ImagePath = "~/images/Test/" + displayimg.Name
                       };
        return myslides.ToArray();*/

        /*
        string[] imagenames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/images/Test/"));
        AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] photos = new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[imagenames.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < imagenames.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] file = imagenames[i].Split('\\');
            photos[i] = new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide("Images/" + file[file.Length - 1], file[file.Length - 1], "");
        }
        return photos;
        */

        AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] slides = new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[4];
        slides[0] = new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide("~/images/Test/ME1.png", "First image of my album", "First Image");
        slides[1] = new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide("~/images/Test/ME2.png", "Second image of my album", "Second Image");
        slides[2] = new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide("~/images/Test/ME3.png", "Third image of my album", "Third Image");
        slides[3] = new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide("~/images/Test/ME4.png", "Fourth image of my album", "Fourth Image");
        return (slides);

    }
}
```

My Web.config (as it also contains code that relates to the Ajax Controls):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="ajaxControlToolkit" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxControlToolkitConfigSection, AjaxControlToolkit" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <ajaxControlToolkit useStaticResources="true" renderStyleLinks="false" htmlSanitizer="AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer.DefaultHtmlSanitizer, AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer" tempFolder="~/Temp" />
  <location path="Temp">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <clear />
      </handlers>
      <modules>
        <clear />
      </modules>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>

  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" />
        <add namespace="InfoBlock" tagPrefix="samples" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager>
      <providers>
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <trust level="Full" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="AjaxControlToolkit" publicKeyToken="28f01b0e84b6d53e" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-18.1.1.0" newVersion="18.1.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

The output looks like this:
[image: SlideShowExtender can't find images]

When trying to debug via F12 > Network, I'm seeing the below (which I don't understand):
[image: SlideShowExtender-undefined-network-debugging]

PS. I'm running this on localhost.

PPS. I'm running Visual Studio 2017 version 15.2 (26430.16) and Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.7.03056. (targetFramework .NET = 4.5.2)

I'd very much like to see the images displayed in a slider on the webpage.
All help is appreciated!

### **Update:**

When experimenting with the Network debugger built in the browser, I noticed the following (screenshot below). It seems like some of my images subfolders (like 'Test') are missing. That would explain why my images can't be found.
Any idea what the cause of this might be?
[image: Network debugger images subfolders missings]

A strange thing is that the debugger shows `slideShowServicePath` while that isn't configured in my .aspx file.

### **Update 2:**

When browsing to *https://localhost:44367/images/Test/* I get the error:

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list
>   the contents of this directory.

After adding `<directoryBrowse enabled="true" />` to the Web.config I can see the folder and images in it via the browser (links to the images, not actual picture). I can then click and view the images.

BUT I can still not see the images in the Ajax SlideShowExtender.

Comment: Is the GetSlides method being called? Is there any javascript errors in console?

Comment: What does your page URL looks like?

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders 
Yes, the method is being called. See `SlideShowServiceMethod="GetSlides"`
The error is: _Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of undefined:1 404 ()_

Comment: @vendettamit Not sure how this is relevant, please elaborate. It runs on localhost, or well it doesn't cause it doesn't work.

Comment: @Dieter There's a possibility that the images are not loading because of relative path. Open the network panel on your browser to debug the Async request. See if the images Url are being returned correctly and you can open them in new tabl using the same. Most likely you are using static path to image in your slide collection i.e. `"images-producten/image1.jpg"`. If that's the issue then try resolving the images path using `Server.MapPath()` method.

Comment: @vendettamit Thank you for your feedback. I updated my question after looking in the network panel of the browser and also tried the `Server.MapPath()` suggestion. Unfortunately, I'm not there yet.

Comment: +1 @vendettamit for guiding me in the direction of the Network debugger in the browser. Issue is still not resolved. See the Update from my question. It feels like we're getting closer to discovering the cause and solution.

Comment: Images under test will load after they are loaded via Ajax request. I think the issue is with your Ajax request as the page is requesting 'http://localhost:44367/undefined' which is probably coming from javascript that is trying to make the request. Debug your Daikin.js file to see what's happening. If possible post the Daikin.js code.

Comment: Hi @vendettamit, I don't have a Daikin.js file in my solution, only aspx and aspx.cs files. I did try to debug the aspx.cs file, I placed a breakpoint on in the method GetSlides, but my breakpoint isn't triggered. Not even after refreshing the webpage manually. In the output from VS I can see some messages saying _code: -32000 message: No script for id: ..._ . After disabling Javascript debugging, I don't see this message anymore. But still, the breakpoint isn't triggered.

Answer (score 1):

The code you are looking is for Vs 2005 and .net 2.0.
The latest working code is here.
Q.There may be something missing or wrong with the ScriptManager, which is configured on my 'Site.master' page and I can't add it to the aspx page as it can only contain one ScriptManager.
**

> A. You have to upgrade project to .net 4.0 and then change web.config
>   also.

**

https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/tree/master/AjaxControlToolkit.SampleSite/SlideShow

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="ajaxControlToolkit" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxControlToolkitConfigSection, AjaxControlToolkit" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <ajaxControlToolkit useStaticResources="true" renderStyleLinks="false" htmlSanitizer="AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer.DefaultHtmlSanitizer, AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer" tempFolder="~/Temp"/>
  <location path="Temp">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <clear/>
      </handlers>
      <modules>
        <clear/>
      </modules>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7"/>
    <machineKey validation="SHA1" decryptionKey="7EE421F6987EAFF4998E0F2ED5544AF1B931C82A1602BC2E" validationKey="5278D83EDD8E36C27E019D3E975D62A3FDF0E8EF50DB69F659D03EB18A4459D2B3271AA075173012EF122E2B7BFA49CDE16CC0DCC68F3E862E1EEE491D300DC9"/>
    <siteMap>
      <providers>
        <add name="SamplesSiteMap" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/Samples.sitemap"/>
      </providers>
    </siteMap>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit"/>
        <add namespace="InfoBlock" tagPrefix="samples"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <trust level="Medium"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>

  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi @Jin Thakur,
I find the github link promising, however, it still doesn't work. It could be me, I'm not that great at this and still learning.
You're saying I have to upgrade to 4.0, but I'm already using 4.5.2.
The web.config you pasted contains 4.7, which I can't use, more errors turn up when I change it and I don't feel like upgrading if not necessary.
I'll update my question with my current Web.config code.

Comment: are you running on IIS ? send me your code i can update it

Comment: I'm running this on localhost and when published on GoDaddy hosting. Both with the same, not working result. How do I send code to you?

Comment: put it on github as private repository add me as user tjitender@gmail.com or https://github.com/jinthakur/

Answer (score 1):

I saw your Question Today...

1. you have add Folder name **"images"**... in your Project with multiple Images...as per Your preference..
2. Add ajax toolkit reference...in .aspx page....

**<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>**

**.aspx Page Code.....**

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnPrevious" runat="server" Text="<<" Font-Size="20" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="300" Width="300" />
            <cc1:SlideShowExtender ID="SlideShowExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="Image1"
                SlideShowServiceMethod="GetImages" ImageTitleLabelID="lblImageTitle" ImageDescriptionLabelID="lblImageDescription"
                AutoPlay="true" Loop="true" PlayButtonID="btnPlay" StopButtonText="Stop"
                PlayButtonText="Play" NextButtonID="btnNext" PreviousButtonID="btnPrevious">
            </cc1:SlideShowExtender>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text=">>" Font-Size="20" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="center">
            <asp:Button ID="btnPlay" runat="server" Text="Play" Font-Size="20" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="center">
            <br />
            <b>Name:</b>
            <asp:Label ID="lblImageTitle" runat="server" Text="Label" /><br />
            <b>Description:</b>
            <asp:Label ID="lblImageDescription" runat="server" Text="Label" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
    </form>
</body>
```

**.cs Page Code...**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using AjaxControlToolkit;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class CS : System.Web.UI.Page
{
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public static Slide[] GetImages()
{
    List<Slide> slides = new List<Slide>();
    string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images/");
    if (path.EndsWith("\\"))
    {
        path = path.Remove(path.Length - 1);
    }
    Uri pathUri = new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute);
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        Uri filePathUri = new Uri(file, UriKind.Absolute);
        slides.Add(new Slide
        {
            Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file),
            Description = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) + " Description.",
            ImagePath = pathUri.MakeRelativeUri(filePathUri).ToString()
        });
    }
    return slides.ToArray();
}
}
```

**Note:- Just Put this code in proper way in your project...this will work...i have already use this code for my Project.....I'm using 3.5 version...**

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. This however is not a valid solution for me, as I have a predefined 'ScriptManager' section in my Master page. This throws an error on the 'ToolkitScriptManager' you defined.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing handler which would handle the requests for 'ScriptResource.axd'

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
<add name="ScriptResource" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: That seems to be missing indeed. Do I need to have that _ScriptResource.axd_ (file?) in my solution? Because I can't find it. Unfortunately, this doesn't resolve the issue yet. I tried adding this handler to the Web.config and kept the _AjaxFileUploadHandler_ in there, but also tried without it.